# Unity - Run a loop like sonic without falling down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, game-development

I am making this 2D platform game for a freelance, and I have to do a sonic mechanic, I have to make the character run through a full loop without falling down, I realised that to do this first I would have to rotate the character conform he runs through the loop, but the second part is where I am stuck.

So, basically, how can I make the character run the loop without falling down.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    Vector3 collRotation = coll.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
    //in this part i rotate the player as he runs through the loop
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, collRotation.z);

        //this is the part that i am stuck, trying to figure out how to make the character stay in the loop without falling, i tried collision detection,
    //i tried raycasting but nothing seems to work
        if (IsGrounded)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.down, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd try experimenting with disabling gravity while in the loop, or changing the direction of gravity. Then if your character falls beneath a certain speed while in the loop or something, return gravity to normal.

Comment: It's really not necessary to do force mechanics for this sort of thing.

Comment: Notice that you use Vector2.down in the AddForce section. This is in global space and will always point downwards, like gravity. If you want to push the character into the loop you should use  '-transform.up'. Don't think this is the best solution but worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick that is most commonly used for remakes and similar is getting the speed of the player character on entry.

```
// Feel free to adjust this to whatever works for your project.
const float minimumAttachSpeed = 2f;

// This should be your characters current movement speed
float currentSpeed;

// You need a Rigidbody in this example, or you can just disable
// any custom gravity solution you may have created
Rigidbody2D rb;
```

If the speed of the character is excelling the minimum attachment speed, you can then allow them to follow a predefined path at that speed.

```
bool LoopAttachmentCheck()
{
    return minimumAttachSpeed <= currentSpeed;
}
```

And now you can check to see if you're moving fast enough! I assume for this example you are using a [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html)...

*(this check should only be run when you're either entering or currently on the loop)*

```
void Update()
{
    if( LoopAttachmentCheck() )
    {
        // We enable this to prevent the character from falling
        rb.isKinematic = true;

        // Here you write the code that allows the character to move
        // in a circle, e.g. via a bezier curve, at the currentSpeed.
    }
    else
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```

It's up to you to implement the actual rotational behaviour. If I were you, a good way to do this would (assuming it is a perfect circle) use [RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) from the center of the circle.

If you have more complex shapes, you can use waypoints for movement, and just iterate through them at your speed.

The moment you fail to keep up speed, your character will fall off (so if a player decided to stop running for example) and the Rigibody2D will become kinematic.

Hope this helps!